# How to setup a file on Xcode to only build on a device and not the simulator?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-flags

How do I set a file say .h or .m (.cpp to be exact) to build only on the devices but not when running on the simulator? This is for Xcode 6.4. The files throw errors when running on a simulator because it doesn't support the architecture.

**EDIT**

Is there a compiler flag to only build file on ARM (Device) and not i86 (Simulator)

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the files in methods and then wrap the methods in this:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
-(void)doSomethingUsingSimulatorOnly {
   //do work
}
#endif
```

with else

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // do stuff when running on Simulator
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    // do stuff when running on actual device
#endif
```

You can also do this:

```
if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {

}
```

Here's another wrapper you can try:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)

#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#endif
```

So, you can do this a bunch of different ways, the last method is easiest to use, but everyone's tastes are different.

Also, here's a snippet that Apple is using in an up to date Metal example, I assume this will work for you, use it as an example perhaps. This is from an ".mm" file used for Metal Video processing, it's the same basic format as above:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus


#endif // cplusplus
```

Comment: I have used my include header to only work on actual phone using this method. But it still builds all the files for simulator even if I didn't include and then throws errors. Right now, It only works if I remove the reference to these files.

Comment: one sec, let me check something

Comment: try the bottom answer, striker, if you are using xcode 6.4

Comment: Hmm the its says "token is not valid binary operator" .. maybe because I am using c++. I also removed the include header but it still builds the files. Is there a compiler flag to only run on ARM?

Comment: but yeah, just checked it, it's probably due to the c++ now that I'm seeing it, let me check one more thing

Comment: So, Striker the last one up there the " if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {} is working, the other two work for me as well, you can use this in your regular code

Comment: let me test c++ real quick

Comment: check those new ones for c++, they shodl work, I',m using files with these if/then combos in projects right now

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the problem still persists even if I don't include the files in the main class. Because it is building the files regardless if they are included or not. I think some compiler flags need to be set so it doesn't compile those files on simulator.

Comment: yeah, your going to have to dive into the settings of the app in Xcode and flag stuff somehow